# Basic javascript validation?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

hello first off i am very new to coding all i have done is made a few html sites so here i am trying to get javascript to validate a text box to see if it has any data imputed into it but at the moment it dosent do anything when i click submit?

```
<script language="javascript"" type="text/javascript">

function validateForm() {
            var result = true;
            var msg="";

if (document.ExamEntry.name.value=="") {
            msg+="You must enter your name \n";
            document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
            document.getElementById('name').style.color="red";
            result = false;
}

if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value=="") {
            msg+="You must enter the subject \n";
            document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
            document.getElementById('subject').style.color="red";
            result = false;
}

if (document.ExamEntry.Examination number.value=="") {
            msg+="You must enter your Examination number \n";
            document.ExamEntry.Examination number.focus();
            document.getElementById('Examination number').style.color="red";
            result = false;
}

if(msg==""){
return result;
}
{
alert(msg)
return result;                
}
</script>

<h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>
<form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="success.html">
<table width="60%" border="0">
            <tr>
                            <td id="name">Name</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                            <td id="subject">Subject</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="subject" /></td>
            </tr>

                            <td id="Examination number">Examination number</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="Examination number" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                            <td><input type="submit"
name="Submit" 
value="Submit"  
onclick="return validateForm();" /></td>
                            <td><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" /></td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: there are a bunch of different input types as well you can use for validation, there are placeholders, character masks etc.  There are a bunch of different ways to handle validation.  It just depends on the routes you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have so many errors in your code.

1- Don't put spaces in any your html properties. `document.ExamEntry.Examination number.value` causes a javascript error. This applies to both the `id` and the `name`

2- You also have a syntax error in

```
if(msg==""){
return result;
}
{
alert(msg)
return result;
```

This is probably what you're trying to do:

```
    if (msg != "") {
        alert(msg);
    }

    return result;
```

3- You have 2 closing quotes in `language="javascript""`

4- You shouldn't call this "onclik" on the button, but "onsubmit" on the `form` itself

5- you have 2 `</body>` tags

**Here's your working code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Exam Entry</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function validateForm(e) {

    var result = true;
    var msg="";

    if (document.ExamEntry.name.value=="") {
        msg+="You must enter your name \n";
        document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
        document.getElementById('name').style.color="red";
        result = false;
    }

    if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value=="") {
        msg+="You must enter the subject \n";
        document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
        document.getElementById('subject').style.color="red";
        result = false;
    }

    if (document.ExamEntry.Examination_number.value=="") {
        msg+="You must enter your Examination number \n";
        document.ExamEntry.Examination_number.focus();
        document.getElementById('Examination_number').style.color="red";
        result = false;
    }

    if (msg != "") {
        alert(msg);
    }

    return result;
}
</script>



</head>

<body>
<h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>
<form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="success.html" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
    <table width="60%" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td id="name">Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="subject">Subject</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="subject" /></td>
        </tr>
            <td id="Examination_number">Examination number</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Examination_number" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /></td>
            <td><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do this by the example:

```
<script>
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("First name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
}
</script>

<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

[source](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_form_validation)